# How do I put characters in front of userInput on a console?

Tags: java, console, command, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am making a console game on [codiva.io](http://codiva.io).. and I would like to put some characters in front of the text of a user's input. Basically, I want to know how to force the user to type in some characters right before they hit enter.

**Example code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("        | Welcome to the [...] Game!\n");
       Scanner useri = new Scanner(System.in);
       String userin = useri.nextLine();
        if (userin.equals("devcom")){
          System.out.println("\nCommands| Communication with developer channel [ACTIVATED]\n");
         Scanner useris = new Scanner(System.in);
          String userins = useris.nextLine();                                          
         if (userins.matches("^~sg\\h+(\\S+(?:\\h+\\S+)*)$")){
           System.out.println("\n>>>>>>>>|");
           System.out.println("Commands| Test command successful. Communication to developer channel [DEACTIVATED]");
           System.out.println(">>>>>>>>|\n");
         }
       } 
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

For normal console output, I use:

```
"        | "
```

And for commands I use:

```
">>>>>>>>| "
"Commands| "
">>>>>>>>| "
```

**My question is, how do I input the normal console output:**

```
"        | "
```

**before the text inputted by the user?**

For example; where it says "devcom", I inputted devcom, (in photo 1), I want it to say:

```
"        | devcom"
```

even though the user only types the "devcom" part.

Comment: `println` adds a newline character after printing.  `System.out.print("   | ");` (followed by the `useris.next();` call) will do what you're looking for.

Comment: @BeUndead I am not quite sure if I understand your answer.. Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/NOkym9).  Unfortunately the 'output' tab on that doesn't copy the stdin to it...  But it works in a normal console.

Comment: Before you use `nextLine();` you can to use `System.out.print("        | ");`, to pre-type it to the console, then when checking the input you need to include it `if (userin.equals("        | devcom")){...`

Comment: @BeUndead It works! What do 'try' and 'final' do?

Comment: `Scanner` implements `Closeable`.  The `try` bit just sets it up to call `close` when the block finishes (otherwise in some consoles, it will hang and not exit the application as it's still waiting for further input).  Search 'try with resources java' for details.  `final` (in this context) just means that once assigned, a variable can't be re-assigned.  Just a habit I've picked up to declare things as such.  Google 'java final' for full details (and a few other uses).

Comment: @BeUndead I did some testing, and I found that adding ```System.out.print("        | ");``` in-between the ```Scanner useri = new...``` and ```String userin = use...``` also works!

Comment: Yes, that's what my first comment pointed out.  If you use `println` (print-line) it prints what you ask and then starts a new line.  If you use `print` it doesn't start a new line afterwards, so user input will be on that same line.

Comment: @BeUndead, oh I didn't quite understand it at that time. I do now though! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

In order to achieve your desired results, you have to put:

```
System.out.print("        | ");
```

in front of the line:

```
String userins = useris.nextLine();
```

This way, before the console can check for the nextLine, you printed the text you want to be before the userInput. Therefore inputting text before the userInput.

Comment: Someone downvoted because I put the correct answer.. why...